# "[Lightweight Function]" in the call stack

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, callstack

I'm debugging a program (VS2008), and I was stepping through lines of code. I came across one line where a delegate function was being called, and I tried to step into it. However, rather than stepping into the method as I expected, the method was bypassed, with the debugger instead stepping into what I assume is a function called by the delegate. In the call stack, the line where I expected the delegate method to be is greyed out with the text `[Lightweight Function]`.

What does the "Lightweight Function" part mean? Is there a way to step into this function?

Comment: Geez, first Visual Studio tells me that "this code was generated by a tool" and now it's calling my functions "lightweight"? What an attitude! :)

Comment: Check you compilation settings, maybe optimalisations are enabled and functions can get optimized away (inlined)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I believe a lightweight function refers to a [DynamicMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.dynamicmethod.aspx), i.e. one that is emitted at runtime, used, and then unloaded.

This blog post is related to Iron Python, but the information should be good for any .NET project: [Viewing Emitted IL](https://web.archive.org/web/20190824082315/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/curth/2008/08/12/viewing-emitted-il/).  The author shows you how to use a lower level debugger (windbg.exe) to see these "lightweight functions."

Answer (score 4):

Looks like this is a [DynamicMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.dynamicmethod). See [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/joelpob/2004/03/31/hello-world-lcg-lightweight-code-gen-style/) for some insight.

I'm not sure about stepping into a dynamic method, though.

Answer (score 3):

Callstack for DynamicMethod (both in Debug and Release mode):

```
[Lightweight Function]  
[Native to Managed Transition]  
mscorlib.dll!System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod.Invoke(object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) + 0x199 bytes
```

Pure

[Lightweight Function]

frame can be observed when **a delegate to a dynamic method** is called.