# Unable to deserialize PSObject in response data contract. Running out of leads

Tags: c#, powershell, wcf, serialization

**Background:**

The company I work at has a product exposed to the network via WCF, specifically, through a service contract containing a single method that handles all messages. Internally, the product parses the SOAP header and body, loads a service plug-in, and routes the request to that plug-in.

I have written one of these plug-ins to host the PowerShell runtime, and provided a custom host that hooks into some of the internal plumbing of this product. A remote client could send an arbitrary script to the server to execute, including taking advantage of functionality of the product itself.

To be clear: I am well aware of the security implications. This plug-in is only for diagnostic and prototyping purposes, not for production use or deployment.

**Problem:**

In the data contract sent back as a response, I am passing an array of `PSObject` instances:

```
[DataContractAttribute]
public partial class RunScriptResponse
{
    [DataMember]
    public PSObject[] Output { get; set; }
}
```

According to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/types-supported-by-the-data-contract-serializer), `PSObject` should be supported; it implements `ISerializable` and boasts `SerializableAttribute`.

The response data contract is getting serialized just peachy by the server, and is being received without issue by the client--as verified by WCF extensibility points. However, when the service client tries to deserialize the objects, I hit this [1]:

`Member 'CliXml' was not found.`

Yet, looking at the response XML, it's pretty darn clear, that member is there:

```
<RunScriptResponse xmlns="...">
  <RunScriptResult xmlns:d1p1="..." xmlns:e="..." xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <e:Output xmlns:d1p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Management.Automation">
      <d1p1:PSObject>
        <CliXml i:type="d3p1:string" xmlns:d3p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
          &lt;Objs Version="1.1.0.1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04"&gt;
```

It suggests that *something* is happening during deserialization where the `PSObject` isn't able to find the `<CliXml>` element, but I can't figure out *why*.

Also, the particular client that is trying to access this server is itself a PowerShell module, dynamically generated from proxy assemblies via reflection. The intent is that you can pass a script to the server, get some `PSObject` instances back, and do further processing on the client.

Given its auto-generated nature, it's not possible to switch to other serialization scenarios, such as serializing the `PSObject` instances on the server, passing an array of strings, and then deserializing them on the client. That would require unique-to-one-method handling, which would significantly complicate the module generation process.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to further troubleshoot this, or other strategies?

Thank you!

---

[1] Stack trace for exception:

```
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo.GetElement(String name, Type& foundType)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo.GetValue(String name, Type type)
   at System.Management.Automation.PSObject..ctor(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
   at ReadPSObjectFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString[] , XmlDictionaryString[] )
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator reader, String name, String ns, Type declaredType, DataContract& dataContract)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, String name, String ns)
   at ReadArrayOfPSObjectFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString , XmlDictionaryString , CollectionDataContract )
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator reader, String name, String ns, Type declaredType, DataContract& dataContract)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, String name, String ns)
   at ReadRunScriptResponseFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString[] , XmlDictionaryString[] )
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator reader, String name, String ns, Type declaredType, DataContract& dataContract)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Type declaredType, DataContract dataContract, String name, String ns)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalReadObject(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator reader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader reader, Boolean verifyObjectName)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.PartInfo.ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader reader, XmlObjectSerializer serializer)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeParameterPart(XmlDictionaryReader reader, PartInfo part, Boolean isRequest)
```

---

**20180129:** The code that I'm using on the client side is plain vanilla WCF. I exported the WSDL and XSDs from the service interface assembly via `svcutil.exe`, ran those back through `svcutil.exe` to generate a C# proxy. From there, everything is just calling the proxy as-is:

```
// Utility code that wraps the programmatic generation of a proxy.
// Manually instantiates `WSHttpBinding` and `EndpointAddress`, then
// constructs an instance of the proxy client using those two objects.
//
var client = GenerateProxyClient<RunScriptRequest,
                                 IScriptingService, 
                                 ScriptingServiceClient, 
                                 RunScriptResponse>();

var response = client.RunScript(new RunScriptRequest
    {
        Script = @"Get-ChildItem C:\"
    });
```

Comment: Where's your code where you're trying to deserialize?

Comment: I would try to simplify this to a small test case and debug. What exactly is the input that the System.Management.Automation.PSObject constructor has received?

Comment: also... is `ReadPSObjectFromXml` implemented by you? Can you share some of that code in your question?

Comment: @veefu `ReadPSObjectFromXml` is not implemented by me (nor is `ReadArrayOfPSObjectFromXml` or `ReadRunScriptResponseFromXml`). To be honest, I have no idea where those particular calls are coming from.

Comment: @veefu I tried implementing the code in a simplified project; the results were different, but no more successful. The objects are being successfully serialized on the server, and I can confirm the client is receiving the full and correct response. However, in the simplified project, I don't get any errors whatsoever, but the PSObject collection in my response data contract is null. It's like it's being skipped completely during deserialization.

Comment: @veefu Turns out the ReadPSObjectFromXml and the other functions may be dynamically emitted. When viewed in the Call Stack window in Visual Studio, they show up as simply "[Lightweight Function]", which apparently means they are [dynamic methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355968/lightweight-function-in-the-call-stack).